# How to stop the ringtone default in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, ringtone

I trying to play a ringtone for the purpose of **alert** user when the notification coming. What i wanna to achieve is the ringtone can be play by user and it not a `default ringtone`.

I successfully to create a `listbox` and ringtone inside the `listbox` can be play in the foreground. But when running in background, the `default ringtone` will alert first and the ringtone play by user will not display. This is what the problem I faced.

**An exception found:**  An exception of type 'System.IO.EndOfStreamException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

**How to stop the** `default ringtone` **so i can play the ringtone selected by user in the background?**

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you.

scheduleTaskAgent.cs

```
 var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sound/" + Ringtone);
 // I using isolatedstorage to store the ringtone name and shared to scheduleTaskAgent.cs

 var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
 FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
 effect.Play();

 ToastHelper.ShowToast("Monitor:", "You have " + read2 + " Invoice!!", null);
 testVibrateControl.Start(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
 testVibrateControl.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the standard OS notification, you are limited to the system sound - you cannot change it and you cannot disable it. However, if the alert is used internally, you might want to take a look at the [ToastPrompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toast%20Prompt&referringTitle=Documentation) control in the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) - once it is displayed, play the sound.

Also, your playback code should look like this:

```
SoundEffectInstance currentSI;
using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("PATH"))
{
    var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
    currentSI = effect.CreateInstance();
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    currentSI.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Den Delimarsky. May i ask we can stop the notification sound tempory and display the (ringtone) it setting by user and play in backgroud?

Comment: You cannot disable the OS notification sound from your application.